# Big wordpress blog causes memory cache to become huge for no good reason

Tags: php, wordpress, caching, memory

I was trying to figure out how much RAM / CPU I needed at a bare minimum to host a wordpress blog, and I stumbled on something rather annoying.

I am using wp_super_cache to create static pages of the wordpress posts and lighttpd + an LUA script to redirect a user to the wp_super_cache-generated page immediatly. This saves *alot* of server resources. Even with a 500 Mhz CPU and 128 RAM I could serve ~120 pages per second.

The only real load comes when wp_super_cache has to generate a html file because none has been made yet, or a post has been updated / a comment added. So this *mostly* happens when a new post is added, because this means all of the index pages need to be updated, because all posts are moved 1 place down. Now have a look at this.

[image]

I don't understand why worpdress is moving so much into the cache. Sure, pages after the initial one take 3 rather than 13 seconds to generate because the cache is only filled on the initial load, but it took 3 seconds in the first place, so why is it loading stuff into the cache at all?

The reason I want to get rid of this behaviour is because I want to host at a *bare minimum* and since I am using wp_super_cahce + an LUA script to redirct there imemdiatly, this caching stuff is making the server (when its at 128 RAM) extremely slow, nearly unresponsive even, for no good reason. Which doesn't make any sense at all because I am basically requesting the exact same page to be generated. I want wordpress to completely ignore the fact there are thousands of post, and just focus on the 10 that are being requested.

**tl;dr version:**

How do I alter the wordpress code so that it completely ignores all posts, except for the ones being requested on the index page(s), to prevent alot of unecessary stuff being written to the memory cache.

PS: I posted this here and not on server fault because I am fairly sure it's wordpress' coding causing this, and not server software.

Comment: Good luck altering wordpress.  It's not exactly the cleanest code in the world...

Comment: That's on of the reasons I'm asking for help, I can't even make sense of it with all of it's includes etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a number of ways to make Wordpress site scalable and in fact WP can appear quite kick ass.

As you have 55000 posts in the blog, i suggest you implement load-balancer and cache content to be served by a different server. It's hard to discuss the whole thing here because it's vast. Check out the video from Ryan Allen from Envato (The company behind Themforest, and all the tuts++ sites) where he describes how they scale WP site. http://blainsmith.com/post/3619881611/scaling-wordpress

When you have this much of posts and i assume they're important. So, you might wanna give a consideration on little more expensive hardware and the cache server, load-balancer solution.